# Does the Scent ability function under water in conjunction with the Aegis' Underwater Breathing Astral suit option?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, aegis

Does the Scent ability function under water in conjunction with the Aegis' Underwater Breathing Astral suit option?

PC in party is an Aegis 4, Druid 7 and managed to get the scent ability, wonders if he can track by scent under water using the that suit option.

> **Underwater Breath**:
>   The aegis can safely breathe underwater as long as he is wearing his astral suit.

https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis/astral-suits

Answer (score 2):

### Ask your GM, but probably not

[Aquatic creatures](https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=006680642033474972217%3A6zo0hx_wle8&q=aquatic%20scent#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=aquatic%20scent&gsc.page=1) generally have [Keen Scent](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Keen-Scent-Ex-), a different Universal Monster ability, that grants them

> The creature can notice other creatures by scent in a 180-foot radius underwater and can detect blood in the water at ranges of up to a mile.

To me, this suggests that Scent is not intended to work underwater even if you are able to breath underwater. They could grant such creatures both scent and keen scent, or decouple the 180ft radius and blood effects into a different ability and leave the with the standard scent ability as well. Instead they made an entirely different effect.